# WIll TIMESTAMP & ORA_ROWSCN be generating for each row?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Mates,

When i'm trying to get Timestamp using following function,

```
SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)
```

got error like

`ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 1`

I want to get the timestamp for SCN generated for the row to handle optimistic locking....

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking in question 1.  I don't understand what timestamp you are talking about in question 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with that sort of approach.

First, unless your table is built with `rowdependencies`, the `ora_rowscn` is stored at the block level, not at the row level.  Second, the `scn_to_timestamp` function can only provide a mapping for relatively recent SCN values, probably on the order of a few weeks at best.  Third, the mapping itself is not particularly accurate-- it's going to be +/- 3 seconds in all versions of 11g, I believe.  The accuracy may be different in other versions of Oracle.  Putting those together, it is unlikely that you could use the timestamp that function provides to implement optimistic locking.

Using the `ORA_ROWSCN` alone is better but it still has [issues if you're trying to implement optimistic locking](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2680538100346782134).  The `ORA_ROWSCN` may make lost updates unlikely enough in your environment to be tolerable but it's not the best approach to implement optimistic locking.

Comment: could you please assist with an alternate if any

Comment: @vinothkumar - Add a timestamp column to the table, modify your code to set that column whenever the data in the row changes, select the timestamp whenever you query the data, and check to see whether the timestamp has changed as part of saving any changes.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I tried this way. I've two tables. Both has id as foriegn key. when insertion happens, i found the recorder time_stamp as 26/11/2014 11:11:59 PM  for one table and 26/11/2014 11:12:00 PM for second. IS  it still possible to use timestamp check to achieve lock with this micro-seconds lag??????

Comment: @vinothkumar - I'm not sure why you would consider two tables having different `last_update_timestamp` values a problem if you're implementing optimistic locking.  So I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: here is my scenario 
I've a id in table A which is foriegn key for table B.
Existing : 
 When i click "Update" button, id will get inserted/updated in table B based on check of ora_rowscn. I'm going to override the use of SCN as it is not reliable. So I come up with your idea of using Mod_timeStamp. so when 
I queried Mod_timeStamp for table A which is say 11.12.00 PM and table B is 11.12.01 PM for that id

both Mod_timestamp & SCN_TO_Timestamp are sometimes matched and sometimes differ by micro seconds......

How can i achieve optimistic lock with this Justin?
If i messed up u , my apologies

Comment: @vinothkumar - Don't use the `ORA_ROWSCN`.  Just use the `Mod_timeStamp` that you are maintaining.  There is no reason to expect the timestamp in the two tables to match or to expect the timestamp from `scn_to_timestamp` to match the timestamp that you are maintaining.